# Notches in newel post of new staircase - what are they for, and how can I improve the appearance?

Tags: woodworking, stairs

I have a newly installed winding staircase in my house as part of a loft extension. The newel posts have notches in them, as shown in the pictures.

My first question is: why are the notches there? I’ve not seen this before, and not knowing a name for them means I can’t Google for answers.

The second question is, what can be done to hide them or make them more attractive? I’ve considered using filler or sanding them down. Is there a standard approach to this problem, or is it just a matter of taste?

[image: Photo of jewel post]

[image: Second view showing that there are 2 notches]

Comment: They look like mistake cuts...

Comment: Could it be a notch for a gate?

Comment: If that is a new install using recycled materials, it was the installers' very poor choice of material preparation....

Comment: unrelated to the your question, but I have to ask - are those pictures real or are they a painting?  looks like a painting to me.

Comment: The ones on the sides look like a second board was attached to the post that was too short to reach all the way to the top.

Comment: Got to agree with @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight the "notch" looks like it was created by _adding_ a board to the outside of the post, not by cutting wood away from a solid piece. Talk to the carpenter who did this and ask what's going on and why he left it this way.

Comment: Is the post step tapered? To me it looks like sloppy carpentry, can’t call that craftsmanship.

Comment: @rothloup - they're photographs taken this morning. There's old paint on the re-used handrail, which gives the picture that strange quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that those notches are just right angle cuts in the facing boards to avoid the line of the ceiling.  It's sloppy work.  Ideally, those boards should have gone another 6-8 inches up to where the plaster meets the left edge of the boards and tapered to match the line of the plaster.

You can add a couple of (roughly knife blade shaped) pieces of the same thickness of wood to the top to finish it.  It's fiddly work (probably why it was avoided in the first place), but if it's done carefully and it will be painted, it should look much more graceful.

Comment: ... which is exactly what I did. Marking this as correct for the benefit of anyone seeing this question in future.